# Are these different versions of completeness or the same?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

When talking about completeness I have come across two versions

> A normed vector space is called complete if every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ (a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$) which has the Cauchy property is convergent in $(X,||\cdot||)$.

Also on first learning about sturm-liouville theory I hear about eigenfunctions forming a "complete set". An example would be to consider

$$y'' = f(x),\quad y(0) = y(1) = 0$$

the eigenfunctions are $y_k = \sin(k\pi x)$ for negative integers $k$. The version of completeness I have in this case is

> $\{y_k\}$ is complete if every $h$ s.t $\int_a^bh^2 < \infty$ can be written as $$h(x) = \sum_{k}^{\infty} c_ky_k$$

I interpret this as:

> every $L^2$ function can be written as an infinite linear combination of $\{y_k\}$.

I am trying to see whether these concepts are related, or even if they are the same thing. We can see some similarity in that in order for the sum to be convergent, the sequence of functions $\{y_k\}$ must be convergent. So would it be correct to take "the eigenfunctions form a complete set" as

- $y_k$ span $L^2(a,b)$
- $y_k$ are Cauchy (?)
- each $y_k$ satisfy the BVP

I am having doubt with the second point as the eigenfunctions we have just talked about satisfy
$$||y_k-y_l|| = 1$$

My question being

> Are these concepts of completeness related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these notions of completeness mean different things. The first refers to [completeness of metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space). We need not have a vector space structure at all. The second refers to [orthonormal bases of Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis). Basically, an orthonormal subset $\Pi$ of a Hilbert space $H$ is called *complete* (or an *orthonormal basis*) if $\overline{\operatorname{span}(\Pi)}=H$.